# Prove region is not simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z=x+iy\in C | 1\lt |z-z_0 | \lt 2 \}$ . ($z_0$ is any point on the plane).

Prove that $A$ is not a simply connected region in $C$.

How can I prove this?  The only idea that comes to my mind is to compute an integral over a closed curve contained in $A$ ,supposing $A$ was simply connected, and then use Cauchy's theorem to get to a contradiction.

Any help will be appreciatted.

Comment: This answer, as it currently stands, is not correct. A region $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected if and only if $A^c=\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus A$ where $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is the Riemann sphere, not the complex plane, is connected. For example, consider the strip $A=\{z\::\:|\Re(z)|<1\}$. This strip is simply connected but $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ is two separate sets. $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus A$ is connected by the point at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

A region $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is simply connected (with respect to the standard topology induced by the Euclidean distance) if and only if $A^c = \overline{\mathbb{C}} \backslash A$ is connected, see for example Ahlfors' book "Complex Analysis", definition 1 on page 139. In your case, you have $A^c = \{|z - z_0| \leq 1\} \cup \{|z - z_0| \geq 2\}$, and this set is obviously not connected, since it consists of two separate point sets. Hence, $A$ is not simply connected. In fact, $A$ is doubly connected, since its complement $A^c$ consists of two components.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the index of $\;z_0\;$ wrt the closed, simple curve $\;\gamma: |z-z_0|=\frac32\;$ is not zero, since

$$n(\gamma,z_0):=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-z_0}=1$$

and from here that $\;A\;$ isn't simply connected.